# 3G Dongle with 3G Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, 3g, dongle

I recently purchased a Vodafone 3G dongle with a TP-Link 3G Router - the router is asking for a handful of information I haven't been provided with (and obviously at the moment Vodafone aren't answering the phone).

I am wondering if anyone has any experience with such or even settings for other carriers when  configuring a 3G router with a dongle?

It is asking for -->

```
APN
Dial Number
Username and Password (I appreciated I will need to contact them about this)
enter preformatted text here
```

Answer (score 1):

it heavily depends on your special contract and country what to setup. Some examples can be found here:
http://www.flexispy.com/Mobile%20APN%20Setting%20to%20use%20GPRS.htm
or
http://www.quickim.com/support/gprs-settings.html

Dial Number mostly is `*99#`